# Adding suffix to values meeting a condition(s) in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset, recode

I am trying to add a suffix letter based on a character value of another variable. Whenever I see an "e" in the category variable, then the id should have three rows like i_C, i_E, and i_O. This means that this id has three dimensions of C, E, and O. That is why I want to have three rows of that specific i.

Here is a sample data:

```
id <- c("i1","i2","i3","i4","i5")
category <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

data <- data.frame("id"=id, "category"=category)
  id category
1 i1        a
2 i2        b
3 i3        c
4 i4        d
5 i5        e
```

I ran this code but it could only produce i1_A.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[category == "e", id := paste0(id, "_", "A")]

> data
     id category
1:   i1        a
2:   i2        b
3:   i3        c
4:   i4        d
5: i5_A        e
```

What I want to have is:

```
> data
     id category
1:   i1        a
2:   i2        b
3:   i3        c
4:   i4        d
5: i5_A        e
6: i5_B        e
7: i5_C        e
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why it is only 3?  Should there be 4

Comment: what do you mean by 3 and 4? The new id should have only three categories: i5_A, i5_B, and i5_C. I do not need i5 anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but here is what I think you are after:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id = paste0("i", seq_len(5)), category = letters[seq_len(5)])
suffixTemplate <- data.table(suffix = paste0("_", LETTERS[seq_len(3)]), category = "e")

suffixDT <- DT[category == "e"][suffixTemplate, on = "category"]
suffixDT[, id := paste0(id, suffix)]
suffixDT[, suffix := NULL]

resultDT <- rbindlist(list(suffixDT, DT[category != "e"]), use.names = TRUE)

setorder(resultDT, id)
print(resultDT)
```

---

Result:

```
     id category
1:   i1        a
2:   i2        b
3:   i3        c
4:   i4        d
5: i5_A        e
6: i5_B        e
7: i5_C        e
```

Comment: Hi @ismirsehregal. Thanks for your response. The suffixes _A, _B_, and _C are independent of categories of a,b,c, and d. I see you were merging id and categories. To make it clear I wanted to have i5_C, i5_E, i5_O. Let me edit that part, might lead to confusion. i5 having the category e means this id has three dimensions of C, E, and O. That is why I wanted to have three rows of i5.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R approach, which could be replicated in `data.table` (I am not good at it) -

```
library(magrittr)

apply(data, 1, function(x) {
  if(x[2] == "e") {
    cbind(paste(x[1], LETTERS[1:3], sep = "_"), "e")
  } else {
    x
  }
}) %>% 
{do.call(rbind, .)} %>% 
as.data.frame()

    id category
1   i1        a
2   i2        b
3   i3        c
4   i4        d
5 i5_A        e
6 i5_B        e
7 i5_C        e
```

**UPDATE -**

Here's a simple `dplyr` approach that can certainly be replicated in `data.table` -

```
df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), 2*(category == "e") + 1)) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(
    id = paste0(id, "_"[any(category == "e")], LETTERS[row_number()][category == "e"])
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  id    category
  <chr> <fct>   
1 i1    a       
2 i2    b       
3 i3    c       
4 i4    d       
5 i5_A  e       
6 i5_B  e       
7 i5_C  e
```

Comment: Nice approach, especially for small datasets. Just one minor comment: The forward-pipe operator `%>%` is not part of base R - you might want to add `library(magrittr)` for future readers. Cheers.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Forgot about that. Thanks!